# Webstorm never show debug warning when application is running

Tags: webstorm

I accidentally clicked "never show warning" checkbox when you start debugging an application when there's a current debug session running. That pop up is very useful for me when I don't know if my application is running already and instead of rebuilding I can just use it.

I've already tried deleting the .WebStorm folder in C:\Users\username\ and uninstalling + reinstalling. I am unable to get the popup to show again.

Is this setting being stored somewhere?

EDIT: I found the exact string.

```
'application' is single-instance run configuration. Are you sure you want to stop the running one?
```

and the checkbox

```
Do not show this dialog in the future
```

Seems like a build configuration setting.

Comment: Open settings and start typing "never show warning".  Sometimes WebStorm hides it's UI but almost every settings page let's you type things in to find them.

Comment: I couldn't actually find it. I had WS installed in my other machine and found the exact pop-up.

"[Application]] is single-instance run configuration. Are you sure you want to stop the running one?"